# Postgresql - search by comparing across rows within groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Table - `grades`:**

```
create table grades
(
  student_id bigserial                           not null,
  course_id  bigserial                           not null,
  score      int                                 not null,
  created    timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
  unique (student_id, course_id)
);
```

**Desired result:**

> Find id of all students, whose score of course 1 > course 2.

**Example data:**

```
INSERT INTO grades(student_id, course_id, score)
VALUES (1, 1, 60),
       (1, 2, 70),
       (1, 3, 65),
       (2, 1, 70),
       (2, 2, 60),
       (2, 3, 80),
       (3, 1, 90),
       (3, 2, 90),
       (3, 3, 85);
```

---

### What have been tried

**Idea:**

- Create a tmp table with each row contains both scores, for a student.
  **gm**: `student_id, score_1, score_2`
- Then query from the tmp table, with condition `score_1 > score_2`.

**Query:**

```
select *
from (
       select grades_1.student_id as sid, grades_1.score as score_1, grades_2.score as score_2
       from (select student_id, score from grades where course_id = 1 order by student_id) as grades_1
              inner join
            (select student_id, score from grades where course_id = 2 order by student_id) as grades_2
            on grades_1.student_id = grades_2.student_id
     ) as gm
where gm.score_1 > gm.score_2;
```

---

### The questions are:

- Is there a better solution? *(For `Postgresql` specifically, if that matters).*
- If the query need to compare 3 or more courses, is there any other solution that would make more sense?
  e.g `course 1 > course 2 > course 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using a simple pivot to isolate and compare grades for the various courses:

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE course_id = 1) AS course_1_score,
    MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE course_id = 2) AS course_2_score
FROM grades
GROUP BY
    student_id
HAVING
    MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE course_id = 1) >
    MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE course_id = 2);
```

You may add another term to the `HAVING` clause to compare other course scores.